# How to copy files from a parent project into a sub project with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to share common static files among multiple subprojects in gradle.  My project structure is as follows:

```
ParentProject
  + subProject1War/
  + subProject1War/
  + src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/
   + css/
     + subProject1/
     + subProject2/
     + common/
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to copy ParentProject's "common" and "subProject1" into subProject1War.

Can anyone provide guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a copy task for that in `subProject1War/build.gradle` and then make the relevant tasks (probably compileJava or processResources) dependent on it so the common files will be available for these tasks during build.

If you'd like all the files under `common` and `subProject1` to be located under `subProject1War/src/css` then you can define the following task:

```
task copyCommon(type: Copy) {
  def cssLib = new File(rootDir, "src/css")
  from "$cssLib/common"
  from "$cssLib/subProject1"
  into "src/css"
}
```

If you want to keep the `common` and `subProject1` folders under `subProject1War/src/css` then your task would look like:

```
task copyCommon(type: Copy) {
  from new File(rootDir, "src/css")
  include "common/**"
  include "subProject1/**"
  into "src/css"
}
```